# What is the maximum size a SharePoint online document library can store?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, administration, limitations

I am reading this SharePoint online limits at [SharePoint Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits) but it did not mention what is the maximum size a SharePoint online document library can hold? or this is applies to the 25 TB which is the Max storage per site (site collection)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard coded limit for the size of a document library in documentation. Technically, a document library can hold large amount of data as long as it doesn’t exceed the limit of a site (site collection).

However, there are limits related to number for files and folders (up to 30 millions) and size limit of each file (250GB) in a document library that you should take into consideration.

You can find these limitations in same documentation at [Items in a list or library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#items-in-lists-and-libraries)